# MySQL alias on group by

Tags: mysql, alias

I have the following mysql query:

```
insert into my_table (col_a, col_b)
select
  col_a, 
  col_b,
  if(foo, bar, baz) as my_alias
from qux
group by my_alias
having my_alias is not null
```

How could I rewrite the query without the `select`-ing the generated field `my_alias`?

For example, I'm trying to achieve something like this where I only insert on col_a, col_b:

```
insert into my_table (col_a, col_b)
select
  col_a, 
  col_b
from qux
group by if(foo, bar, baz) as my_alias
having my_alias is not null
```

I found some previous answers where this is done by making a sub-select. Can this be achieved without one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual tells us](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> MySQL permits expressions in GROUP BY clauses, so the alias is
>   unnecessary:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, FLOOR(value/100)   FROM tbl_name   GROUP BY id,
> FLOOR(value/100);
> ```

The HAVING filters out the NULL record at the end. We can also use a WHERE to filter out the NULL records at forehand. That would mean that this should work:

```
insert into my_table (col_a, col_b)
select
  col_a, 
  col_b
from qux
where if(foo, bar, baz) is not null
group by if(foo, bar, baz)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jasny. I'm trying to use the alias because the real "`if(foo, bar, baz)`" is `big` and `ugly`. :)

Comment: Thanks for referring me to the manual. I guess this is not possible.